# С чего начать изучение в C#?

Tags: c#

Я создавал подобную тему по Java. Я определяюсь, какой язык учить пока. Меня интересует, с какой литературы начинать изучение C# и в каком порядке человеку, не имеющему опыта в программировании и где брать задания для закрепления теоретического материала.

Comment: А еще, для более точного совета, чем планируете дальше заниматься, веб или десктоп программирование? Потому как книги, что я дал ниже это лишь основы, дальше прийдется изучать конкретные технологии более глубоко.

Comment: Я планирую заниматься веб.

Answer (score 4):

- Джеффри Рихтер - CLR via C#.
     Программирование на платформе
     Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 на языке
     С# (Есть 3е издание по .Net 4, но на
     англ. языке.)
- Троелсен Эндрю - Язык
     программирования C# 2010 и платформа
     .NET 4

Все книги есть сами знаете где, по понятным причинам ссылок не даю.

Comment: Да Энрю Троелсен обширная книга,есть книга "Учимся программировать на C# с Джоном Смайли" простая основы ообъясняются,а вот потом начинай с Энрю.

Comment: А что вы скажете, если перед этими книгами прочитать книгу Шилдта C#, полное руководство.

Comment: Можно и его,у него хорошо рассказываться про ООП,он автор многих книг как на С++ так и на Java, так что можно и его практиковать.

Comment: CLR via C# это точно не та книга, с которой стоит начинать изучать C#. Особенно человеку не имеющему опыта в программировании. Откройте эту книгу и прочитайте первый раздел первой главы - "Компиляция исходного кода в управляемые модули". Я не думаю, что новичок, что-то поймет из этой главы.

Comment: >Кстати у Вас устаревшая информация, уже вышло 4-е издание и на русский уже перевели :)

вы бы еще Лермонтова упрекнули в том, что у него не было айфона. Иными словами, обратите внимание на то, когда был дан ответ, который вы комментируете - два с половиной года назад

Answer (score 2):

**Joseph Albahari, Ben Albahari - C# 4.0 in a Nutshell, 4th Edition** - лучше чем у Рихтера некоторые аспекты и мой личный фаворит,
а если с самых азов, то [Программирование на C Sharp (Си шарп) с нуля](http://simple-cs.ru/)

Comment: Албахари замечательны, присоединяюсь.

Comment: Албахари - это,конечно, очень здорово. Весьма достойная книга отличных авторов.
 А вот что касается приведенного ниже некоего сайта, то материал на нём - это низкокачественное барахло. Огромное количество фактических ошибок, не компилирующиеся, и что ещё хуже, неверно работающие примеры кода (а местами и вовсе огрызки такового), крайне поверхностное изложение. Чего стоит только "статья" об интерфейсах размером аж в 8 (!!!) строк текста и с десяток строк кода. Плюс куча грамматических ошибок и прочих мелких грешков вроде режущего глаз косноязычия и неумения грамотно изъяснять мысли
Sad but tru

Comment: В продолжение к предыдущему комментарию о чудо-сайте. Вот небольшой пример этого благолепия (разумеется, я не взял на себя ответственность изменять пунктуацию и орфографию оригинала) : 
**"В Си Шарп делегат это нечто указателя на функцию в других языках программирования. 
Делеагы выполняют туже самую функцию, но более удобно и безопасно, то есть основное назначение это обратный вызов 
то есть это посылка сообщения объектам, которые их породили"**

А [вот так][1] кратко и без лишней воды нам рассказывают о тонкостях юнит-тестирования в Visual Studio и C#. Краткость - сестра таланта, не иначе

Answer (score 1):

Михаил Фленов - Библия C#. Хорошая и понятная книга для новичка, сам по ней учился.

Comment: Фленов совершенно кошмарен

Comment: Соглашусь Фленова лучше не брать в руки

Answer (score 1):

Как новичку посоветовал бы "Бибилию С#" Михаила Фленова.

Answer (score 0):

Насчёт практики, попробуте вот это:  http://www.videosharp.info/   достаточно просто и понятно человек всё объясняет, что оченно редко  в наше время.

Comment: хм... не сторонник видео курсов вообще, а таких в частности, но если хотите видео курсы то тогда лучше MVA http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/#?fbid=GysbnHdFASq
или 
http://www.techdays.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Книгу лучше в книжном магазине посмотрите. Разным людям нужно разное чтиво. А за практикой - сразу джуном в контору - это однозначно, лучше не найдёте практики.

Comment: >Книгу лучше в книжном магазине посмотрите. Разным людям нужно разное чтиво

любопытно, каким образом именно в книжном магазине можно определить качество книги? Спросить у продавца? Прочитать несколько глав в процессе выбора? Или просто по цене?

Answer (score 0):

Учить Оба и C# и Java. А начать с концепции понимания объектно ориентированного подхода. Адекватно понять суть полиморфизма и инкапсуляции. Уяснить раз и навсегда для себя что такое управляемая куча и стэк. Понять суть коллекций и структур. И только тогда начинать закреплять всё это. А познавать лучше параллельно теорию и практику... На мой взгляд самая понятная и достойная книга для изучения C# это [C# 5.0 и платформа .NET для профессионалов](http://www.dialektika.com/books/978-5-8459-1850-5.html).