# Задачи по C#

Tags: c#, книги

Здравствуйте. Какие практические (задачи) книги есть по c#?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

- [С чего начать изучение в C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22794)
- [Отзывы о книге Карли Уотсон, Кристиан Нейгел - Visual C# 2008: базовый курс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/31815/)

Answer (score 0):

книга `Ватсон Б. "С# 4.0 на примерах"` построена по принципу **Задача => Решение**

> Описание: На практических примерах
> рассмотрено программирование на языке
> Microsoft С# 4.0, начиная с основ
> языка и заканчивая решением типичных
> задач с помощью .NET Framework.
> Показано создание эффективных классов,
> интерфейсов и типов, а также
> программного кода, допускающего
> многократное использование. Описаны
> приемы обработки данных, основанные на
> применении коллекций, сериализации,
> баз данных и XML. Рассмотрена
> реализация пользовательского
> интерфейса с применением технологий
> WinForms и WPF, а также создание
> веб-приложений на основе технологий
> ASP.NET и Silverlight. Показано
> применение на практике новых
> возможностей языка С# 4.0. Уделено
> внимание взаимодействию с ОС Windows и
> системным ПО, использованию шаблонов
> для разработки сложных программ и
> другое. Приведено более 200 готовых
> решений, оптимальных технических
> приемов и примеров проверенного кода.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO,С# часто обновляется,лучше начинай Java или PHP .

А если по сути то "Учимся программировать на C# вместе с Джоном Смайли " поймешь основы,там пишут программу(приложение) для вычисления среднего балла по семестру.
P.S. Дальше больше.Удачи в начинаниях.

Comment: >IMHO,С# часто обновляется...

что вы имели ввиду под этой фразой?

Comment: В шарп всегда что то новое добавляется постоянно,не успеваешь походу следить,из-за чего я его и бросил(хотя сильно нравился) =)

Comment: <pre>
C# 1.0    Январь 2002
C# 2.0    Ноябрь 2005
C# 3.0    Ноябрь 2007
C# 4.0    Апрель 2010
C# 5.0    ~~~~~~ 2012
</pre>

обновляется примрено раз в 2 года, а это не такой уж и маленький срок

Comment: Я имел ввиду то что много всего меняется в целом да и добавляется,что не скажешь о Java и PHP .Меняются но только с исправлением "багов" и по функционалу.

Comment: увы, это отдальная тема для разговора.

Comment: Ты прав,этот разговор не к месту)